# Unite two arrays

Tags: vhdl

I want to make one array out of two.

```
TYPE        character_string IS array (0 TO 15) of unsigned (7 DOWNTO 0); 
TYPE        full_string IS array (0 TO 31) of unsigned (7 DOWNTO 0); 
SIGNAL  lcd_oben, lcd_unten             : character_string; 
SIGNAL  lcd_data                                : full_string;
```

And i want to take the two smaller arrays and put them togehter in the big one.
Something like this:

```
lcd_data    <= lcd_oben & lcd_unten;
```

But that gives the error:

```
Error (10327): VHDL error at seqdec.vhd(55): can't determine definition of operator ""&"" -- found 0 possible definitions
```

Can anybody help?

Best regards
Adrian

Answer (score 3):

You have declared these as wholly unrelated array types, so you have told the compiler not to mix them together without type conversions.

I don't think that's really what you wanted to do.

Make both array types, subtypes of an unconstrained array, like `array(<>) of unsigned(7 downto 0)`. Then they are not completely separate types and there should be a predefined `&` operator for them.

```
TYPE        LCD_string IS array (natural range <>) of unsigned (7 DOWNTO 0); 
SUBTYPE     character_string IS LCD_String (0 TO 15);
SUBTYPE     full_string IS LCD_String (0 TO 31);
```

(Alternatively you can write your own `&` function which performs the necessary conversions; IMO this would be poor design).

Comment: There's likely no advantage to using subtype declarations. Object declarations (signal lcd_oben, lcd_unten: *LCD_string(0 to 15)*;`) provide a subtype indication, "A subtype indication defines a subtype of the base type of the type mark." (IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.3 Subtype declarations, para 4). Using a named subtype as a type mark in an interface object (e.g. a function header) can require those same excoriated type conversions while as Brian demonstrates you can count on operations of the base type. Are there operations that should only be performed on a subtype?